# Sanditthika Sutta: Visible Here-&-Now

Tags: pali-canon, mindfulness

In the [Sanditthika Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.047.than.html),

> "The fact that when a delusive quality is present within you, you discern that a delusive quality is present within you; and when a delusive quality is not present within you, you discern that a delusive quality is not present within you"

A similar description is also given in the Satipatthana Sutta. The second part, "to know when something is not present inside of me", is to be understood how? Do I literally acknowledge at any point in my daily life that I have currently no defilements in me? And if the answer is yes, what do I do with that acknowledging?

Comment: See also [this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26226/254) which tries to define "delusion".

Answer (score 1):

The four right efforts in the noble path are:

1. effort to prevent unwholesome mental states.
2. effort to abandon unwholesome mental states.
3. effort to develop wholesome mental states
4. effort to maintain & increase wholesome mental states

Therefore, when the mind without delusion is discerned, the effort is made to maintain the mind without delusion, which requires governance or supervision by mindfulness.

Comment: I never understood the first point. By that we mean sense restraint, right? How is that achieved? If I see tasty food or an attractive woman I have to reconsider the objects? Avoiding the objects might be good but it doesn't address my underlying desire, aversion and delusion.